# How to define modules and submodules in Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a library in Swift, and I want to have multiple modules and submodules, for example:

```
Sources
  |-Org
  |-Shared
  |-Client
      |-Handlers
```

In the example above, *Handlers* should be a subfolder and submodule of *Client*.

But when I try to declare the *Handlers* submodule inside the *Packages.swift* file, I get an error.

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "Sdk",
  platforms: [.macOS(.v14)],
  products: [
    .library(
      name: "Org",
      targets: ["Org"])
  ],
  targets: [
    .target(name: "Org", dependencies: ["Client", "Shared"]),
    .target(name: "Shared", dependencies: ["Client"]),
    .target(name: "Client", dependencies: ["Handlers"]),
    .target(name: "Handlers", dependencies: []),
  ]
)
```

The error:

```
swift build
error: 'sdk': Source files for target Handlers should be located under 'Sources/Handlers', or a custom sources path can be set with the 'path' property in Package.swift
error: ExitCode(rawValue: 1)
error: 'sdk': Source files for target Handlers should be located under 'Sources/Handlers', or a custom sources path can be set with the 'path' property in Package.swift
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

What is the correct way to declare a module's submodule in Swift?

Comment: There is no such thing as "Submodule" in Swift. You can probably set up paths for folder Client/Shared to contain a separate module but it will be very difficult to maintain and you won't gain anything from it.
Just use a subfolder. There is no reason to define a special module for every subfolder.